# xcb memory management: Should I free data field in iterator?

Tags: xcb

There is a group of functions for iteration on some list property in xcb. They all end with `iterator`. For example, `xcb_setup_roots_iterator`. And there are corresponding functions ending with `next` or others for iteration.

Here comes the problem:
Should I call `free` on the `data` field of iterator when I no longer need the data?

Here is a sample.

```c
  int screen_num;
  xcb_connection_t *connection = xcb_connect(NULL, &screen_num);
  const xcb_setup_t *setup = xcb_get_setup(connection);

  xcb_screen_iterator_t iter = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup);
  for (; iter.rem; xcb_screen_next(&iter)) {
    xcb_screen_t *screen = iter.data;
    /*do something with screen*/
  }
  /*should I free iter.data here?*/
```

I know `iter` is on stack so it will be destroyed automatically. But what about `data` in it? In my thoughts xcb creates it and after using it I never pass it back to xcb so xcb has no chance to free it and I should manually free it to avoid memory leaks.

After searching the docs and web, I only find some limited info about memory management such as:
I should always free the return value of `xcb_wait_for_event`.
What about other places? What's the general principle of memory management in xcb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: No, you should not free it.

Long version:
Here is the implementation of `xcb_screen_next`:

```
void
xcb_screen_next (xcb_screen_iterator_t *i)
{
    xcb_screen_t *R = i->data;
    xcb_generic_iterator_t child;
    child.data = (xcb_screen_t *)(((char *)R) + xcb_screen_sizeof(R));
    i->index = (char *) child.data - (char *) i->data;
    --i->rem;
    i->data = (xcb_screen_t *) child.data;
}
```

As you see, this only does some pointer magic to compute the size of the screen and then incremenets the pointer by that amount, i.e. the new `data` member points just beyond the end of the last screen.
Put differently: all screens are right behind each other in memory in a single, big allocation.

> I should always free the return value of xcb_wait_for_event. What about other places? What's the general principle of memory management in xcb?

xcb does not really do any parsing. Instead, it describes the on-the-wire protocol as C `struct`s and provides some convenience methods for working with these. This means that a single X11 "packet" is read from the connection and put into one big memory region. Everything else is just pointer magic to get into the individual fields.

Since you are asking about `xcb_screen_t`: This is part of `xcb_setup_t`. When connecting to the X11 server, a single `xcb_setup_t` is received. This is put in one big allocation which you can access with `xcb_get_setup`. This memory is owned by libxcb and freed by `xcb_disconnect()`.

What else are "packets"? Well, every reply, event, and error is a single packet. Thus, you have to free whatever you get from `xcb_wait_for_event()`, but also `xcb_*_reply()`. Nothing else needs to be freed.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer! I'll keep digging deep into X protocol and xcb. You really give me a good guide.

Comment: do you know what exactly a `xcb_screen_t` refers to? Is it the number of monitors or the windows?

Comment: To answer myself, `xcb_screen_t` refers to the screen on which all windows and monitors are placed. It's just one level above the DISPLAY server. Also windows and monitors generally remain on the screen they were initially placed, and cannot be moved to another screen. This is why when you connect to an X server, you are asked which screen to connect to, and it will by default pick screen 0. What really helped solidify this for me is this answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503884/44793